# Silverlight project won't enter debug mode

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

My Silverlight project in VS 2010 has stopped entering debug mode.  Even if I set a breakpoint in the constructor of the Application class, it refuses to hit any breakpoints.  My other projects are still fine, but I can't find any setting that may have accidentally gotten changed to keep me from debugging.  What could be going on?

Comment: What do the debugger icons look like? Are the full red or hollow circles? That will tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what happened, but here's what got it working again.

I changed it to Release mode, compiled it.  Closed and restarted VS, changed it back to Debug mode, ran it and breakpoints hit again.

Comment: Had the same issue. I checkd the .Web solution -> Web -> debuggers and selected Silverlight

Comment: @Random - Thank you! This solution worked for me. However, VS did not need to be restarted in my case. I compiled first in Release mode, then in Debug mode, and started the application with a break point. Break point was hit this time.

Answer (score 6):

Open the properties of the associated Web Project.  Select the Web Tab.  Scroll to the bottom and in the "Debuggers" section make sure "Silverlight" is Checked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dropdown in the toolbar is set to Debug and not Release

Comment: Yep, that was the first thing I checked.  Debug it is.

Answer (score -1):

While Attaching the process please attach w3p.exe and iexplorer instance of Silverlight this should resolve your issue.